# Can using twitter bootstrap cdn make this huge difference in performance of my site?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, lighthouse

In my laravel project I used artisan to install bootstrap and it automatically bring a file app.css and app.js which is basically bootstrap. So when i used lighthouse to check and performance of my site i found a huge difference in using cdn and using that bootstrap copy. So it it true that using cdn is better than using a copy in the server?

With laravel bootstrap copy in the server:
[image]

Without bootstrap at all:
[image]

With bootstrap cdn:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using cdn will better your performance to a great length.

Some of the [benefits of using a CDN](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/)?

- **Improving website load times** - By distributing content closer to website visitors by using a nearby CDN server (among other optimizations), visitors experience faster page loading times. As visitors are more inclined to click away from a slow-loading site, a CDN can reduce bounce rates and increase the amount of time that people spend on the site. In other words, a faster a website means more visitors will stay and stick around longer.
- **Reducing bandwidth costs** - Bandwidth consumption costs for website hosting is a primary expense for websites. Through caching and other optimizations, CDNs are able to reduce the amount of data an origin server must provide, thus reducing hosting costs for website owners.
- **Increasing content availability and redundancy** - Large amounts of traffic or hardware failures can interrupt normal website function. Thanks to their distributed nature, a CDN can handle more traffic and withstand hardware failure better than many origin servers.
- **Improving website security** - A CDN may improve security by providing DDoS mitigation, improvements to security certificates, and other optimizations.